# Energy of the nucleon bag (MIT bag model)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, nuclear-physics

I am studying MIT bag model.

The Lagrangian density for this model is $$ \mathcal{L} = (i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi - B)\theta_V - \frac{1}{2}\bar{\psi}\psi\delta_S .$$

The nonlinear boundary condition of the MIT bag model is $B = -\frac{1}{2}n\cdot\partial[\bar{\psi}\psi]_{r = R}$, where $B$ is phenomenological energy density term added to Bogolioubov model for conservation law of energy-momentum tensor.

We can get the energy of the nucleon by calculating $P^0 = \int d^{3}x T^{00}(x)$ and the energy is

$$E(R) = \frac{\sum{\omega_i}}{R}+\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3B.$$

This model implies that $\frac{\partial E}{\partial R} = 0$ but, I can not understand how this result came out because here is an assumption of the model that $B$ is constant.

So I would like to show that

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial R} = -\frac{\sum{\omega_i}}{R^2}+4\pi R^2B = 0.$$

Can I get some advice for it?

I am studying this model with 'Chiral symmetry and the bag model : A new starting point for nuclear physics, A. W. Thomas, 1984'. In this text, author said that we can explicitly show this result but I failed.

Comment: So, what, exactly, is your problem? That energy is energy density integrated over volume?

Comment: Yes, $ B $ is the vacuum energy density. What I asked is "How partial derivative of energy with bag radius becomes zero?". Is this stability equation obvious?

Comment: ?? You mean how is a minimum-energy configuration for a bag of  labile size most stable?

Comment: Because it has radiated away all excess energy and cannot lose more.

Comment: Well, I'm not clear yet. But I can keep thinking about it. Thank you very much for your precious comment :)

Comment: Prof. @CosmasZachos gave a nice answer, but since you mentioned that it not quite clear I attempted another approach. It is not using the non-linear boundary condition, and hence if you don't like the answer I will delete it. As you see it was not easy to write the answer as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prof. Zachos gave a nice and clean argument, however since there is a comment that his reply is not yet very clear let me venture a different approach. If my answer is not satisfactory, let me know and I will delete it.

What I understand from the comments is that you need some clarification for the minimum.

Consider the function $E(R)$ rather than its derivative. For $R<<$ the dominating term is the $1/R$ and at $R \rightarrow 0$ we have $E(R \rightarrow 0) \rightarrow \infty$ (assuming that the $\omega$ are positive). On the other hand, as we approach infinity the $1/R^3$ dominates the description of the function and we have $E(R \rightarrow \infty) \rightarrow \infty$.

You can plot the function

[image: The Energy plot]

Inspection of the plot reveals a minimum and at the minimum, the derivative will be zero.

Let me also post a [link](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/astro/AST3220/v19/undervisningsmateriale/?page=2&u-page=2) that uses the above logic. I would post directly the link to the pdf-file, however it is not preferred in the site. You want to go on page 2 and check problem 8.